# Clarification on how this function is returning values and using partial functions

Tags: scala

I get confused when I see a function that looks like this:

```
def site(req: RequestHeader, emit: ClientEmit) = WebSocket(req) { sri => user =>
```

Source: [here](https://github.com/ornicar/lila-ws/blob/bf5147ab8e875d4f653f7c23ee677a07772fe907/src/main/scala/Controller.scala#L23)

I want to recreate a very simple function that follows the same pattern to solidify my understanding on what's going on here.

The function calls `WebSocket`, and then seems to pass another function call in the body of the outer function site.

Where does `sri` and `user` come from?  They are not in scope?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  WebSocket is a method in that file. https://github.com/ornicar/lila-ws/blob/bf5147ab8e875d4f653f7c23ee677a07772fe907/src/main/scala/Controller.scala#L160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block `WebSocket(req) { sri => user =>` in your sample is just call `WebSocket` method. Your block is equivalent to:

```
def site(req: RequestHeader, emit: ClientEmit): Response = {
  return WebSocket(req)(
    new Function1[Sri, Function1[Option[User], Response]]() {
      override def apply(sri: Sri): Function1[Option[User], Response] =
        new Function1[Option[User], Response]() {
          override def apply(user: Option[User]): Response = ??? 
      }
    }
  )
}
```

calling WebSocket method here `sri => user => *do something* and return Response` is a syntaсtic sugar for two Function1 objects with apply methods creating actually. Short note is a two lambda expressions. Just read a little more about expressions and lambda expressions. If function contains just one expression, curvy braces are not required and you can write only one WebSocket method call and pass to him lambda expression as a function from 1 argument witch creates function from 1 arguments witch creates Response object.

take a look at `WebSocket` method:

```
private def WebSocket(req: RequestHeader)(f: Sri => Option[User] => Response): Response =
  CSRF.check(req) {
    ValidSri(req) { sri => auth(req) flatMap f(sri) }
  }
```

I wrote here his extended version:

```
private def WebSocket(req: RequestHeader)(f: Sri => Option[User] => Response): Response =
  CSRF.check(req) {
    new Function0[Response] {
      ValidSri(req) {
        new Function1[Sri, Response]() {
          sri: Sri =>
          val futureOptionUser: Future[Option[User]] = auth.apply(req)
          futureOptionUser.flatMap {
            optionUser: Option[User] =>
              val fAppliedToSri: Function1[Option[User], Response] = f.apply(sri)
              val response: Response = fAppliedToSri.apply(optionUser)
              return response
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

in `flatMap` method **function composition** occurs and it's **not** the same as Function of 2 arguments but in this case it's equivalent. Function composition is more flexible pattern then Function of 2 arguments, you can evaluate them not in the same moment. If you want to know more about conversion between Function of 2 arguments and 2 function of 1 argument composition read about [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) .

Comment: Is not a **Function2** is a **Function1[Sri, Function1[User, Response]]**

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you are right, updated answer

Comment: Its confusing.  Shouldn't it be ```WebSocket(req) { (sri, user) => ```

Comment: @coolbreeze according this project API it shouldn't be function of 2 arguments. Look at my updated answer.